# error after joomla upgrade 2.5.3 to 2.5.6

Tags: joomla, upgrade, fatal-error

I have a fatal error after upgrading joomla from 2.5.3 to 2.5.6 and couldnt find any solutions on all the forums. After failed to upgrade joomla via the admin backend, I downloaded and installed joomla upgrade 2.5.6 using the install extensions panel. And it said that installation was successfull.

Afterwards loging in to the admin panel, everythings is empty, only the "view site" and "logout" buttons to the top right are visible.

On the frontend following error is shown.

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /homepages/44/d33570217/htdocs/joomla/libraries/joomla/application/menu.php on line 90

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /homepages/44/d33570217/htdocs/joomla/includes/application.php on line 449

Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /homepages/44/d33570217/htdocs/joomla/includes/application.php on line 471

Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /homepages/44/d33570217/htdocs/joomla/templates/beez_20/error.php on line 10

the upgrade must have overwritten some files and I cannot localize the problem. It is not a template problem, I have tried switching it in the database. Configuration.php is also ok, all values are identical to before the upgrade.

Can someone help me to find out the problem? Thanks

Comment: If you have access to the FTP, try downloading the full Joomla 2.5.6 package, then uploading the "libraries" and "includes" folders.

Comment: Thanks a lot this did bring back front-page and backend and I can work now. Could you explain what caused the problem? Now the modules are all giving out an error. Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /homepages/44/d33570217/htdocs/joomla/modules/mod_random_image_extended/helper.php on line 194. Any idea where i can resolve this? Thanks a lot for your adivce!

Comment: Im not entirely sure what was causing the problem but maybe the upgrade wasn't complete. Whenever I get errors coming from core Joomla file, the first thing I try is uploading the "includes" and libraries" folder. As for this problem, try disabling the Random Image module or replacing it in the FTP.

Comment: I see, good to know. Thank you! I already tried to uninstall and reinstall the modules, but it didnt solve the problem. 1 other module (eventlist module) is doing the same. both show the "Creating default object from empty value" error on the helper.php - I couldn't find any solutions on forums yet. Disabling the modules make the error disappear, but also the module, which is needed.

Comment: have you edited any of the files for the event list module?

Comment: no, didnt edit anything. update probably also overwrote something here. dont know where to start searching...

Comment: next time you update, don't use extension manager. Extract via the FTP. only thing I can think of is downloading the event list again and replacing the helper.php see if this gets rid of the error.

Answer (score 0):

This happens sometimes because of a session issue. Try logging out with the button to kill the old session. Also once in go to the database tab and check for updates.